# How can I insert dynamic output inside printf?

Tags: c, arrays, function

Suppose I have a function that prints all integers from 1 to N , N - user input integer.

This function is of `void` type:

```
void number(int integer)
```

So I want to print on the screen :

> "The range of number is (1 2 3 ..... N) " .

As you can see, it is supposed to print only one sentence, but inside the brackets the variables should be able to change, as the user wishes.

I have tried to wrap my head around it, but I just can't get it done, and cannot integrate one into another.

So I'm curious at this point if it's even possible to do it in C at all.

Comment: Post what you've attempted so far along with the input, expected output, and actual output.

Comment: Of course it is possible to do this very basic thing. Do you know about `for` loops? Any loop for that matter will do the job.

Comment: There is no coding reason why a "sentence" has to be output all in one instruction. The outside world won't know about that, all it will see is a single sentence.

Comment: Why do you need to print every number? If `N` is 42000 that will be unwieldy. People can usually understand something like "The range of number is (1 thru 42000)."

Comment: Sidenote: `()` are called parentheses in the standard. `[]` are called brackets.

Comment: @Olaf the brackets used in a "sentence"  are not part of the C syntax.

Comment: C is turing-complete, so of course you can output what you show. That does not mean you can print in with a single output function call. You need to learn the basics of the C language to accomplish this output.

Comment: @WeatherVane: It is in general a good idea to stick to common nomenclature. This question **is** about C, is it? (An you might have noticed the "sidenote" intro, which provides additional information, not a correction).

Comment: @Olaf the common nomenclature is "brackets". The language (or high-brow) nomenclature is "parentheses". You are picking holes where none exist.

Comment: @WeatherVane: With all due respect, but I prefer the definition of [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/parenthesis). Parentheses is unambigous, while brackets has various semantics, this can be missleading. And it is not me picking on a hole which has a "closed" sign on it already. Who is the worse nit-picker? The nit-picker or the one nit-picking on the nit-picker? :-)

Comment: The C spec calls `()` parentheses and `[]` brackets.  Perhaps "but inside the brackets the variables should be able to change" is better stated as "but inside the _parentheses_ the _values_ should _not be fixed, but 1 to `N`_".

Answer (score 3):

Most people would just break the output up over multiple `printf` calls.

```
printf( "The range of numbers is (%d", 1 );
for ( int i = 1; i < N; i++ )
  printf( ", %d", i+1 );
puts( ")" );
```